# Is there a function that allows me to use the weeknumber in a MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to perform a query in MySql based on week number. The function I found ('WEEK()') gives me the week number for a certain date. However, I would like to use the week number as the date range, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM x
WHERE price > 1
AND start_date_column between (start week 41 and end week 41)
```

Does anyone know of a function that could I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`WeekofYear()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) function as well. It returns the calendar week of the date as a number in the range from 1 to 53. Sunday is considered as starting day of the week in this function. For eg:

```
SELECT WeekofYear('2018-10-18'); -- returns 42
```

You can do the following using the above-mentioned function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM x
WHERE price > 1
AND WeekofYear(start_date) =  41
```

---

Even [`Week()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function would work as well, in the similar fashion:

```
SELECT * 
FROM x
WHERE price > 1
AND Week(start_date) =  41
```

Comment: But the input should be the week number, not the date.

Comment: AND WeekofYear(start_date) between (41 and 41) 

I get an error when using it like this.

Comment: Just to be clear, start_date is a column in my database

Comment: @nemja you dont need to use `between` if start week number and end week number values are same. check the update answer please

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Comment: please be super carefull with only "week()" checking in your conditions. At least include Year() as well (so you wont get false positives from last year etc)